# Is there a way in C# of programmatically determing whether a link target has been found?

Tags: c#, shortcut-file

I would like to determine programmatically whether a link target has been found from C#. Using the code `link.Resolve(SLR_FLAGS.SLR_UPDATE)`  a dialog box appears saying that link target cannot be found and giving the option of deleting the shortcut.

Code for generating the link is

```
Type t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application");
dynamic shell = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
var folder = shell.NameSpace(pathOnly);
var folderItem = folder.ParseName(filenameOnly);

string sAbsPath = "";
if (folderItem != null)
{
   (Shell32.ShellLinkObject)folderItem.GetLink;
    var link = folderItem.GetLink;
 }
```

If I add the option to suppress the UI using `link.Resolve(SLR_FLAGS.SLR_UPDATE|SLR_FLAGS_NO_UI)` the option not to delete the shortcut is taken and link.Path still refers to the file whose location has not been found. In this situation, the link object appears to have no attributes indicating that the link target has not been found. Does anyone know a method of doing this?

Comment: Your question doesn't tell us which Shell COM interfaces you're using. We need to know those details.

Comment: Added detail of code used to generate link to original post

Comment: What's wrong with taking the file path can calling `File.Exists()`?

Comment: File.Exists() can tell if the target exists, but cannot tell if the file has been moved to another location or renamed. The great virtue of Windows shortcuts is that it can track files by a unique Tracking ID, so the shortcut automatically updates to point to the new path on access unless the file has been deleted or moved to another server. It is this condition that I want to detect. Perhaps one method is to try and access the Tracking ID directly without using a shortcut.